# property not updated when I update UI using a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using a Converter to display a property into a XAML MVVM view.

```
   <xctk:DoubleUpDown  Value="{Binding CurrentIndex, Converter={StaticResource IndexToNumberConverter}} />
```

When the code updates the property, the IndexToNumberConverter.Convert(...) method in invoked and runs as expected.

I would have expected that the property updates when I update the control from the UI.
This is not what happens.
Instead, the COnvertBack method of the controller is invoked and the property setter is not run.

I suppose, that it would work if I pass my property as the argument of the converter and then implement the converter convertBack method to do the appropriate job.
But I am pretty sure that it is not the correct way to proceed :)

Isn't there an easier way to just update my property when I update the UI control?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Convert runs when data flows from the view model to the view.  ConvertBack runs when data flows from the view to the model.  You have to implement both if you want to support two way bindings.  Your ConvertBack method must convert the data from the view into the appropriate data for your view model, or it will not be saved.  As you haven't shown either, I can't say as to what your problem may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your changes on the UI to reflect back on your ViewModel you'll need a twoway binding. I don't know what your control does, but I'll show it with a TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" />
```

The `Mode=TwoWay` enables this TextBox to trigger changes made on the UI back to the ViewModel. The TwoWay mode is default on a TextBox, I don't know if it is enabled on your control by default.

If you use a ValueConverter you need to implement the ConvertBack, like others already mentioned. Again, no idea how your code looks like, but something like this will work.

```
public class IndexToNumberConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        switch(index)
        {
            case 0:
                return "ZERO";
            case 10:
                return "TEN";
            default:
                return "OTHER";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string val = value.ToString();
        switch(val)
        {
            case "ZERO":
                return 0;
            case "TEN":
                return 10;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the bound control will look like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IndexToNumberConverter} }" />
```

If you want your binding to be from UI to ViewModel only you need to specify `Mode=OneWayToSource`.

I hope this helps, otherwise I advise you to update your question with more relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Bart :)

Answer (score -1):

As from your query i have understand that the property not converting back while you are setting from ui. I think the problem is you have not implemented iPropertyChange interface into your property,that's why the property not updating the affected values.

Comment: actually, Ionly want the bound property to be updated when the UI control is updated. just as if there were no converter.
However, I do need the converter to apply when the code updates the property.

Comment: You have to use convert back method as well. Along with this in your viewmodel or wherever you have created property that should have to implement INotiFicationPropertyChanged Interface.

Comment: Please refer this link for property notificatio.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx